# Visual studio code extension to cleanly indent existing html code

Tags: html, visual-studio-code, laravel-blade

I currently have a blade file whose html tags indentation is pretty messed up.

I just want to know if there're any extensions I could use to clean and indent all of HTML tags on an existing blade files?

I've been searching for an hour now for an extension and I just can't find any.

Comment: you could just do `shift` + `alt` + `F` to format the code itself. is that what you're looking for?

Comment: I also found this [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46268211/how-to-format-laravel-blade-codes-in-visual-studio-code) page which might help you